# Google Apps email forwarding to a mailbox within the same domain

Tags: email, g-suite, mail-forwarding

It's either me or this feature doesn't work.

I have a Google Apps account (non-paid) for `example.com` set up fine and dandy. Among other addresses, there are `support@` and `employee@`.

Now I want to set up Filters such that all mail sent to `support@` should be forwarded to `employee@`. Note that this is *not* POP3/IMAP forwarding: I really need to do this with filters.

The problem is as such: when an email arrives to `support@` it is never ever forwarded to an address within the same domain, but is forwarded perfectly fine to some "outside" address (for instance, forwarding to my personal GMail account works flawlessly).

How do I set up Filters to forward email propely?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps they want you to use the Groups feature whereas support@example.com would be a group address with employee@example.com (and whomever else) as a member of that group.

http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33329

Comment: definitely the best way.